# How to rename a project and its namespace in Ranorex?

Tags: ranorex

Since the naming of our project changed, I would like to concistently reflect that change in project-names and namespaces within my solution. Also, the standard test suite file files (.rxtst, .rxtmg, .rxrep) should be renamed accordingly.

What I tried:

Renaming the solution and projects within the Ranorex IDE works fine.

Renaming the standard test suite files in the Ranorex IDE will rename all references, except for references to the repository within CodeModule files. These will point to the previous repository name, resulting in compile errors.

Renaming the namespaces in the Ranorex IDE is not supported. Renaming (refactoring) the namespace in Visual Studio works in that the solution will compile just fine afterwards when compiled in Visual Studio. However, opening the solution in the Ranorex IDE will regenerate the code of recording modules, which still point to the previous, no longer valid repository name, resulting in compile errors.

Any suggestions how to handle the scenario efficiently, consistently and correctly?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

Close the solution in Ranorex.

Replace all occurrences of the current project name by the new name within the solution directory (e.g. Notepad++ feature, replaces all occurrences within a directory). Given that the namespace is the same as the project name, a single replace iteration suffices.

Then: (if you use a CVS, use that system for renaming)

1. Rename the project directory accordingly
2. Rename the test suite files within the project directory. The following ones are named after or similar to your project per default in Ranorex (7.0)

   - .csproj
   - .csproj.pref
   - .csproj.rxuser
   - .rxtmg
   - .rxtst
   - ~project~Repository.cs
   - ~project~Repository.rximg
   - ~project~Repository.rxrep

Open the solution in Ranorex, clean the solution and rebuild it to check if everything still works fine at first glance.